# maven-compiler-plugin with eclipse Helios and galileo

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

i have a problem with maven-compiler-plugin:
when i do command:
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
Result:

```
[INFO] >>> maven-eclipse-plugin:2.10:eclipse (default-cli) @ XXXXXXXX >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-eclipse-plugin:2.10:eclipse (default-cli) @ XXXXXXXX <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-eclipse-plugin:2.10:eclipse (default-cli) @ GT_XXXXXXXX ---
[INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: null
[INFO] Adding default classpath container: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5
...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

in workspace, file .classpath i have this:

```
<classpath>
    ....
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5"/>
  ....
</classpath>
```

[image]

but my problem i like set the JRE_CONTAINER to Workspace default JRE in Eclipse.
my default JRE is another ( you can see it in image), result like this:

```
<classpath>
    ....
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  ....
</classpath>
```

i have try it in eclipse Helios su windows and eclipse galileo su Ubuntu, but i have always the problem

**Information:**

pom.xml

```
      ....
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
          <encoding>utf8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ....
```

Maven:

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 17:22:22+0200)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre
Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 0):

solution found.
the solution is set the `maven-compiler-plugin` in `pom.xml` like this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
      <classpathContainers>
           <classpathContainer>
org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER
           </classpathContainer>
          </classpathContainers>
          <encoding>utf8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

tks